# Adding TextView inside ListView with PullToRefresh in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, textview

I have a `ListView` where I should store some results from a network request.
If there's any problem with the server, I need to add a `TextView` to that `ListView` (and show only that `TextView`) and still being able to pull to refresh (that comes integrated with my `ListView`).
In case the network request goes fine, I want to populate the `ListView` as normal, with an `Adapter`.

Is it possible to add that `TextView` to the `ListView` programmatically, depending on the network response?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is creating an .HTML file and storing it in the assets folder.
Then I created a `PullToRefreshWebView` and loaded that HTML in case something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your information `TextView` as `ListView`'s row (i.e. very first) and remove it if it is no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

You want to show TextView **instead of** ListView or show that TextView in every row of ListView? If second, add this TextView to xml of the item of ListView and in adapter make it visible only if there's problem with the server. If first, consider adding TextView to xml where there's your ListView and in case of problem make it visible and ListView gone, and vise versa.

Answer (score -1):

Put a TextView just below or above the Listview and make it invisible and whenever u get network error make ListView invisible and TextView visible and reverse it when network connection is working fine.

Comment: and how am I supposed do the pull to refresh if the ListView is hidden?